# How to execute some python statements after executing external shell commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm developing a Django application and it uses FFMPEG. Basically it receives a video uploaded by the user and it uses FFMPEG to transcode it to 240p, 360p and 480p. Since this is server-side code, many users might upload at the same time. Also after transcoding, records are added into a database table.

```
out="media/uploads/"+folder #This is the upload path where folder is the name of the video

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

command = "ffmpeg -i '"+os.path.join(BASE_DIR,out)+"/"+fname+"' -s 426x240 '"+os.path.join(BASE_DIR,out)+"/240p.mp4'"
subprocess.call(command,shell=True)
convert = Convert.objects.get_or_create(vid=rec,name="240p.mp4",video=str(out+'/240p.mp4'))

command = "ffmpeg -i '"+os.path.join(BASE_DIR,out)+"/"+fname+"' -s 640x360 '"+os.path.join(BASE_DIR,out)+"/360p.mp4'"
subprocess.call(command,shell=True)
convert = Convert.objects.get_or_create(vid=rec,name="360p.mp4",video=str(out+'/360p.mp4'))

command = "ffmpeg -i '"+os.path.join(BASE_DIR,out)+"/"+fname+"' -s 854x480 '"+os.path.join(BASE_DIR,out)+"/480p.mp4'"
subprocess.call(command,shell=True)
convert = Convert.objects.get_or_create(vid=rec,name="480p.mp4",video=str(out+'/480p.mp4'))
```

As this code will be run on a server, multiple users might upload videos at the same time. I want this code to run without any problems in that scenario. Also the database operations must be executed only after the FFMPEG commands have been executed.

What are the changes that must be done to this code?

Comment: You can use `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory` to create a temporary folder so that the files don't collide with each other.

Also - please, please DON'T use `shell=True` here. Any uploader with control of `fname` could use this shell injection to exploit this and get access to your server. You can call it with a list of arguments instead.

Comment: for a more scalable and production ready solution a task queue such as Celery should be used imo;

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could put an answer with the replacement code please.

Comment: It's really difficult to help without being in your team as there are lot of dependencies; I actually asked few people for suggestions, they suggested that if this is running on AWS cloud, then we can setup something like AWS sqs work queue -> lambda function for ffmpeg + db update; Also running ffmpeg and django can cause a bottle neck as both are cpu bound; might effect your // reqs concurrency as well;  + look if you can leverage asyncio as well here; good luck